# Finding partial derivative plug in a value?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y)=x^2\arctan\frac{x}{y}$ find $F_x(-1,1)$ $F_y(-1,1)$

for

$\frac{d}{dx}=2x\arctan\frac{x}{y}+x^2\frac{y}{y^2+x^2}$ the plugging in (-1,1) I got

$-2(\pi/2)+\frac{1}{2}$

for

$\frac{d}{dy}=x^2-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ plugging in

I got (1)-1/2

But I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: for $\frac{d}{dx}$ I got the same but not for $\frac{d}{dy}$ I got $$\frac{d}{dy}=x^2\frac{1}{1+(x/y)^2}(-x/y^2)=\frac{-x^3}{y^2+x^2}$$ so for $(-1,1)$ I get $1/2$

Comment: Also, you have not evaluated the $x$ derivative properly. $\arctan(-1)$ is not $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $F_x$, we have 
\begin{align}
F_x &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x^2 \tan^{-1}\frac{x}{y})\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (x^2) \cdot \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{y} + x^2 \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{y} \\
&= 2x \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{y} + \frac{x^2}{y} \frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{y})^2}
\end{align}
So 
\begin{align}
F_x(-1,1) &= 2 \cdot (-1) \cdot \tan^{-1} (\frac{-1}{1}) + \frac{(-1)^2}{1} \frac{1}{1 + (\frac{-1}{1})^2} \\
&= 2 \cdot (-1) \cdot -\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{\pi + 1}{2}
\end{align}

For $F_y$, we have
\begin{align}
F_y &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  (x^2 \tan^{-1}\frac{x}{y}) \\
&= x^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \tan^{-1}\frac{x}{y} \\
&= x^2 \frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{y})^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (\frac{x}{y}) \\
&= x^2 \frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{y})^2} (-\frac{x}{y^2})
\\
&= \frac{-x^3 y ^2}{1+(\frac{x}{y})^2}
\end{align}
So 
\begin{align}
F_y(-1,1) &= \frac{-(-1)^3 (1)^2}{1+(\frac{-1}{1})^2} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}